# How to write WinForms Designers in NET 6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, form-designer

I need to create WinForms project with components under the .net library version 6.0.
But when I create the project and the ControlLibrary the Visual Studio Form designer doesn’t use ControlDesigners from the ControlLibrary, even though I correctly bind designers to the component.

```cs
  [Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
  [ToolboxItem(true)]
  public class MyControl : Control 
  {

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Info, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
      e.Graphics.DrawString("MyControl", Font, SystemBrushes.InfoText, new PointF(0, 0));
    }
  }
```

I have created some ActionLists but they are not showing up in the component at design-time.

```cs
namespace WinFormsControlLibrary1
{
  internal class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
  {
    private DesignerActionListCollection actionLists;

    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists
    {
      get
      {
        if (actionLists == null)
        {
          actionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
          actionLists.Add(new DataAxisGridActionList(Component));
          actionLists.AddRange(base.ActionLists);
        }
        return actionLists;
      }
    }
  }

  public class DataAxisGridActionList : DesignerActionList
  {

    public DataAxisGridActionList(IComponent component) : base(component)
    {
    }

    public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems()
    {
      DesignerActionItemCollection items = new DesignerActionItemCollection();
      items.Add(new DesignerActionMethodItem(this, "Action1", " Action 1", true));
      items.Add(new DesignerActionMethodItem(this, "Action2", "Action 2", true));
      return items;
    }

    public void Action1()
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Action 1");
    }

    public void Action2()
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Action 2");
    }
  }

}
```

For the test, I created a similar project and library under the .NET Framework 4.7.2 and the designer works correctly there.

[image]

[image]

I am also attaching a link to demo projects.

https://github.com/dmitrybv/WinForms-Net5-Designers

https://github.com/dmitrybv/WinForms-Net-Framework-4.7.2-Designers

Answer (score 4):

For now, given the not yet completely finalized nature of the Design-Time support in the new Out-Of-Process architecture of the WinForms Designer, probably the simpler solution is to install the WinForms Designer Extensibility SDK.

It's available via NuGet Package Manager, using the name:  [Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK)

or paste in the Package Manager Console:

```
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK -Version 1.6.0
```

or add the Package Reference to the Project's configuration file in an existing `<ItemGroup>` of `<PackageReference>` (or create a new one):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK" Version="1.6.0" />
```

A description of the current state of the Designer support can be found here:
[State of the Windows Forms Designer for .NET Applications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/state-of-the-windows-forms-designer-for-net-applications/)

---

Add the required using directives in the code file that contains the custom Designer (`ControlDesigner` and `DocumentDesigner` support):

```
using Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Designers;
```

For Behavior Services and Adorners (glyphs) that can receive hit test and paint messages:

```
using Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Designers.Behaviors
```

Comment: And what technology do standard designers like System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewDesigner use? After all, all standard WinForms controls work fully.

Comment: You're asking to extend the Design-Time support when you build your own Designer. Which require the ability to derive from an existing, supported, Designer, generate code for it, provide serialization support via CodeDomSerializer, etc. I.e., extend the built-in functionality to custom, user-provided code. Hence `WinForms Designer Extensibility` SDK. It will be integrated seamlessly as in .NET Framework in time -- You probably have noticed that the OOP Designer is still in the Preview features in the general settings of Visual Studio

Comment: There's also the option to multi-target your .NET application, including .NET Framework, then link the .NET Framework Project that provides the functionality. I didn't mention this because it's a real hassle. A NuGet Package that provides the functionality by itself is way more *convenient*, IMO